include path error in visual studio code in Mac operating system
i am trying to run a simple c++ program
#include<math.h>
#include<limits.h>
#include<iostream>

int main(){
    return 0;
}

math.h is detected easily, limits.h is also detected easily, but iostream is not detected, even though math.h and iostream are in the same folder - "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX15.0.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1", whereas limits.h is in "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/16"
this is my c_cpp_properties.json file
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/16/include/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Library/Developer/**"
            ],
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "${default}",
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang++"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}

actually it was working fine in the previous OS version (14), but not working in 15.
please tell me what to do.
output error
[i am using an extension "c/cpp compile run" by danielpinto8zz6, here is the settings screenshot.
screenshot of c_cpp_properties
i have tried running updating the commandlinetools and restarting the computer many times

``c_cpp_properties.json is settings for the editor, not for the compiler. See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac

This question is similar to: How do I set up Visual Studio Code to compile C++ code?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
